# Cassandra, ¿Cómo comparar un campo con la fecha actual?

Tags: funciones, cassandra, time

Buenas,
Soy nuevo usando Cassandra, he estado buscando información en la página oficial y foros pero no termino de resolver las dudas que voy a plantear.

En primer lugar tengo un archivo .csv ,desde donde cargo los datos de los últimos jugadores de la copa mundial de fútbol, para posteriormente generar consultas sobre ellos.

Mi archivo csv tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
Grupo; Equipo; Número; Posición; Nombre; Día; Mes; Año; Club; Liga; Capitán
A; Brasil; 1; PORTERO; Jefferson; 2; 1; 1983; Botafogo; Brasil; NO
A; Brasil; 2; DEFENSA; Dani Alves; 6; 5; 1983; FC Barcelona; España; NO
A; Brasil; 3; DEFENSA; Thiago Silva (c); 22; 9; 1984; Paris Saint-
```

Basándome en los datos, creé la siguiente declaración para generar mi nueva tabla: 
**CREATE TABLE players (GRUPO text, EQUIPO text, NUMERO int, POSICION text, NOMBRE text, DIA int, MES int, AÑO int,  CLUB text,  LIGA texto, CAPITAN text, PRIMARY KEY (NOMBRE));**

Aquí tengo mi primera pregunta, lo que he hecho es crear un campo int para cada uno de los campos, día, mes y año. ¿Sería posible encapsular esos tres datos en un formato, por ejemplo, DATE? 
¿Para que en futuros cálculos, no tenga que comparar los 3 campos uno a uno?

En definitiva, me gustaría saber si esos tres campos en la tabla podrían ser encapsulados en un formato de fecha, llamémoslo DATE o algo similar.

Aquí está mi segunda duda; Si yo, por ejemplo, quisiera obtener el jugador más longevo, he estado pensando en comparar la fecha actual con los campos de día, mes, año de los jugadores de los diferentes equipos que tengo.

Este es el problema, ya que no he encontrado en la documentación cómo realizar este tipo de consulta y cómo comparar tres datos en mi tabla con alguna función que me devuelva la fecha actual, o como comparar la fecha actual con un formato DATE o un formato que me encapsule mis tres campos DIA,MES,AÑO.

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero es que si creas un campo de tipo `date` vas a poder almacenar ahi la info correspondiente a los campos `DIA`, `MES` y `AÑO`. Pero eso por si solo no te va a permitir la comparación. Pues en Cassandra solo se puede buscar usando columnas que pertenezcan a algún indice (ya sea la clave primaria o un indice secundario). Y en el caso de la tabla descrita solo es posible buscar por el campo `NOMBRE`.

La forma de comparar con la fecha actual seria comparando el valor del campo con `dateof(now()))` o con `toTimestamp(now()))`.

Seria posible crear una tabla con una estructura mas apropiada para este problema. Pero me parece que los datos no son Big Data y por tanto te beneficiarias de usar una Base de Datos Relacional.